# Kafka to Spark integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to pull data from kafka to spark, a simple example from spark docs. But While executing :

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.1.1\
             examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py \
             localhost:9092 test
```

I get:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.
    : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.setStreamingJobProgressListener(Lorg/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener;)V
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.ui.StreamingTab.<init>(StreamingTab.scala:41)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:192)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:76)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:130)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
            at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
            at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'm using scala 2.11, Spark 2.1.1 , I have tried the new spark 2.4.3 but I read that Python isn't supported, hence 2.1.1, and used both spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 and spark-streaming-kafka-0-10, but no hope. Please help.

Comment: @Jasurbek, Thanks for the edit.. Any suggestion on this query?